# An invalid controller has been detected. Perhaps, one of your controllers is missing @Controller() decorator

Tags: typescript, nestjs

When I run my nestjs application, This error occurs saying

````
(node:71496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: An invalid controller has been detected. Perhaps, one of your controllers is missing @Controller() decorator.```
````

And the log trace :

```
(node:71496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: An invalid controller has been detected. Perhaps, one of your controllers is missing @Controller() decorator.
    at RouterExplorer.extractRouterPath (/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-explorer.js:57:19)
    at /node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/routes-resolver.js:39:53
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at RoutesResolver.registerRouters (/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/routes-resolver.js:36:16)
    at /node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/routes-resolver.js:32:18
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at RoutesResolver.resolve (/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/routes-resolver.js:30:17)
    at NestApplication.registerRouter (/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:110:29)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async NestApplication.init (/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:95:9)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Not sure which controller is it? How to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So NestJs won't tell you using stack trace if there is a problem with the controller or the module.

I found out that if I wrongly added another class to the list of controllers, this will throw the same error.

Used git to manage the error.

**Found out using git, I wrongly added a listener to controller options.
I added it to providers and it fixed the problem.**

Check screenshot. Remove unwanted classes from the controllers section of the module.
[image]

Comment: I've just made a PR to improve the error message here: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/10479 :)

Comment: @MicaelLevi thanks, PR looks great. Thanks for this. More power to people like you who take matters in their hands for the better good of the community.

Comment: thank you for these kind words <3 I'm trying my best to help on keeping the framework alive and well-maintained